# size command in form parsley.js

Tags: forms, input, size, parsley.js

I am building a form using Parsley.js, but the size command does not work:

```
<input type="text" size="2" id="month" value="" 
       data-parsley-type="digits" 
       data-parsley-length="[2, 2]" 
       data-parsley-error-message="Expiration Month is Required" 
       data-parsley-required />
```

Can anyone suggest an other way of doing this, or is it a bug..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? 


The size attribute defines the width of the input (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp).


If your trying to force the user to insert 1-2 characters, it might be easier to do that using jquery (through the event keypress, for instance).

Also note `data-parsley-length="[2, 2]"` is forcing the user to insert two digits. If the month is May, the user will have to insert '05' since '5' will result in a failing validation.

Answer (score 0):

The `size` attribute you refers to is perfectly working. It affects the input width (the box, not its content). Try putting 10 or 20 instead, and you'll see the box size changing accordingly.

Maybe you are referring to `maxlength="2"` attribute, that prevent user to enter more than 2 characters in the input box? (That is working too with Parsley)

Best